# How to extract number from text in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, extract

My product names contain different sizes: e.g. 100ml, 50ml, 30ml.

Sample product name:

```
Babaria Aloe Vera Shaving Gel Sensitive Skin 200ml
```

From this I try extract capacity: 200ml.

To make it easier to do this, I am sharing a document.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gPuNiNwvK1bG5WxD-4kFgrYjSF72SkwX/view?usp=sharing

Could somebody help me and give me some example?

If it's hard to extract numbers with "ml", it also might be helpful for me to extract only numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
=INDEX(IF(A2:A="","",REGEXEXTRACT(A2:A,"\b\d+ml\b")))
```

Where `\b\d+ml\b` means:

- `\b` - A word-boundary to assert position has no leading word-characters.
- `\d+ml` - 1+ Digits followed by literally "ml".
- `\b` - A word-boundary to assert position has no trailing word-characters.

If you just want the numbers without "ml" then try to change the pattern to `\b(\d+)ml\b` where the only difference is the use of a capture group which will be the result of the `REGEXEXTRACT()` function here.